# Ruby function to capitalize all words in a string

Tags: ruby

The task is to write a function, which capitalize the first letter of all words in a string. For this we'll class a word as any characters separated by a blank. Because the standard [`String.capitalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-capitalize) method only capitalizes the first character of the string I have written the following.

Could the task be accomplished with writing less code? Any other improvements-suggestions concerning the function?

Here's the code I have written:

```
def capitalizeAllWords(str)
    caps = str.split(" ").map do |word| 
        word.capitalize
    end
    caps.join " "
end

puts capitalizeAllWords "Red orange green blue indigo violet" 
# Prints: "Red Orange Green Blue Indigo Violet"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a one liner. If you want to get fancy checkout Rail's implementation https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize

```
str.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

Comment: Cool! Exactly, what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. At least add *some* remarks on the original code. *What do you think of the five lines?* Afterwards, please explain your reasoning (why your code is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using a regular expression. like this:

```
def capitalizeAllWords(str)
  str.gsub(/\b\w/, &:capitalize)
end
```

where `\b` matches a work break and `\w` matches a word character